# Update Operations in a java HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, garbage-collection

I'm using a `HashMap` in java 11 to store a `String` and `Object` mapping.
The logic:

```
if (map.containsKey(someStringValue)) {
   Object existingItem = map.get(someStringValue);
   updateSomeValueInEntity(existingItem);
}
else {
   Object someEntity = generateNewEntity(someItemId);
   map.put(someStringValue, someEntity);
}
```

This code works since `map.get()` would return the reference of the value. The update operation on this reference would in turn update the value in the map for that particular key. Therefore, I need not do `map.put()` for the updated value or any other fancy map functions available such as `replace()` or `compute()`.

Looking at these new HashMap functions, I'm wondering if my code would cause any memory issues. It technically shouldn't since I'm updating the same reference associated to the key without creating any new assigned references which I might not use there by missing out on garbage collecting and causing memory issues.

I'm still curious if for my use-case I need to use HashMap update methods or if my implementation is fine and has no memory wastage concerns.

Comment: We'll need to see the code in `updateSomeValueInEntity()`

Comment: `cause any memory issues.` The main concern I'd have is memory visibility / thread synchronization.  Mutable objects can have issues there.  But it also depends on your intended use of this map, and we don't know that.

Comment: updateSomeValueInEntity() essentially just updates some Integer fields in the Entity. It's just a simple value change based on some logic, I thought it was irrelevant here.

Comment: The values of the map would be eventually collected as an ArrayList()

Comment: Since `HashMap` is not thread safe, concurrent access is out of the game anyway. For single threaded access, this works without problems. You may still avoid unnecessary hash lookups by omitting the `containsKey` check. Just use `get` in the first place and check the result for `null`. Using `compute` can even avoid the double hash lookup in the case of an absent mapping, but this may be overkill. As a reminder, before Java 8, we used `HashMap` exactly that way, without `compute` or `replace`, for more than a decade…